# Binance US api STOP_LOSS trade not executing nodejs (node-binance-us-api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance, binance-api-client

If anyone has any experience with the BinanceUS api please let me know if you have had this problem.
I have read the docs thoroughly and can not come up with an adequate solution. Yes I have read the docs for both BinanceUS and node-binance-us-api. This is a test of a STOP_LOSS data object to be sent with credentials/apikeys/secrets. It is not working and I can not find an answer anywhere as this appears to be the correct method. But when I do regular buy and sell orders they work. I am at a loss, thanks for anyone's’ help!
The `object`

{

“symbol”:“SHIBUSDT”,

“side”:“SELL”,

“type”:“STOP_LOSS”,

“quantity”:“1200000”,

“stopPrice”:“0.00001150”,

“timestamp”:1667507603276,

“recvWindow”:5000

}

As stated I have read both API docs and I am in need of someone with more experience with binanceUS API than I.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through post req, logs, etc I finally found the answer. Binance does not allow "STOP_LOSS" even though it says that is a correct "type" of trade in the API DOCS. However, if you go-to https://api.binance.us/api/v3/exchangeInfo and parse through the data you will find:

```
"orderTypes":["LIMIT","LIMIT_MAKER","MARKET","STOP_LOSS_LIMIT","TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"]
```

This is because Binance does not allow STOP_LOSS I am assuming because it executes the trade at "market price". However, with STOP_LOSS_LIMIT you also have to pass the limit price you would like to sell at, if the "STOP" price is reached. The correct way would have been:

```
{

“symbol”:“SHIBUSDT”,

“side”:“SELL”,

“type”:“STOP_LOSS_LIMIT”,
 
“price”:“0.00001147”, //<----needed with STOP_LOSS_LIMIT

“quantity”:“1200000”,

“stopPrice”:“0.00001150”,

“timestamp”:1667507603276,

“recvWindow”:5000

}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use for LONG:

> ```
> Quantity = float(1) #This means 1 BNB u can change what ever u want 
> symbol = 'BNBUSDT'
>
> #=====LONG-BUY======            
> BUYorder=client.futures_create_order(
>     symbol=symbol,
>     side='BUY',
>     type='LIMIT',
>     quantity=Quantity,
>     price=280,
>     timeInForce='GTC')
> print("1-Orders sent")
>
> #=====LONG-TP======                   
> TPsell=client.futures_create_order(
>     symbol=symbol,
>     side='SELL',
>     type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET',
>     stopPrice=300,
>     closePosition='true')   
> print("2-TP is set")
>
> #=====LONG-SL======                
> SLsell=client.futures_create_order(
>     symbol=symbol,
>     side='SELL',
>     type='STOP_MARKET',
>     stopPrice=250,
>     closePosition='true')   
> print("3-SL is set")
> ```